# Rails 3: form_tag to check code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, tags

I have my posts generating a :key_code when created. I want a user to be able to use that code in a form field to destroy the post they made, without being signed in. My difficulty is with form_tag... how could I make a form_tag view to check the :key_code entered with the one stored in the database? I'm having a hard time understanding form_tag.

My route looks like this:

```
get 'posts/:id/code' => 'posts#code', :as => :code
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly then your route is wrong as you need a dynamic param `code`, so you should use `:code` instead of simply `code`:

```
get 'posts/:id/:code' => 'posts#code', :as => :code
```

To generate a url to that route in `form_tag` you use:

```
form_tag code_path(@post, :code => @post.key_code)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Looks like that's a big part of the problem. What would you do about the needed controller-side code? Store it in that 'code' method in the posts controller? Also, do you happen to have any good resources that helped you understand all these conventions you used?

Comment: Not sure if I can't point to any specific resources. Regarding the controller stuff: I would not create a separate `code` action as you already have a `destroy` method, but I would change the way user authorization works for `destroy` action to allow authentication by `params[:code]`. So you can then destroy posts with usual URL with code param: `DELETE /posts/1?code=xxx`